# Program executing past last curly bracket

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm having an issue with some code I wrote where the program doesn't stop after reaching the last curly bracket. At least that's what I'm seeing with the debugger.

```
    public static void infoSpout() {

    System.out.println("Filler Text");

    Scanner s2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    conf = s2.nextLine();

    while (suc == false) {

        switch (conf.toLowerCase()) {
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
                conf = s2.nextLine();
                continue;
            case "yes":
                suc = true;
                break;
            case "no":
                System.out.println("The program will now reprint the information spout");
                conf = null;
                suc = false;
                infoSpout();
            case "stop":
            case "quit":
                System.out.println("Program closing.");
                System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    suc = false;
}
```

Pretty much what the debugger is telling me is if you enter "No", and then enter "Yes", the code executes properly until it hits the last }. Then, it bounces back to:

```
System.out.println("Program closing.");
System.exit(0);
```

I've never encountered this before and it's really frustrating me. I realize this may be a very stupid question but I'm new to java and am trying to learn how to avoid stuff like this. Does anyone know what's happening, why, and how I can fix it?

A couple notes:
`suc` and `conf` are both public variables from my main class. `suc` being a boolean and `conf` being a string.

Comment: You do not include a `break` statement after your `no` case.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to do that! Thank you!

Comment: As a note, this is one example of why conditionals (like switch) can be tricky. An alternative in more complicated programs would be a `Map<String, Runnable>`, where you could simply do `commands.get(conf.toLowerCase()).run()`.